# Order a collection by type with specific counting

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Not quite sure how to explain this, but here's my try:

On a webpage I need to show **References** and **Quotes** in one list. First I need to show 4 References *(image, title, link)*, then 1 Quote *(quote, author)* and then again 4 References, 1 Quote and so on.

I have records coming from two different sources. One called References and the other called Quotes.
They are now inside a big collection that hold both of the sources.

Now I need to find a way to actually get them sorted by this sequence:

- Reference 1
- Reference 2
- Reference 3
- Reference 4
- Quote 1
- Reference 5
- Reference 6
- Reference 7
- Reference 8
- Quote 2

Makes sense?

This is the code of my specific ReferenceItem class, the one I use to create a collection with both the datasources in it.

```
public class ReferenceItem
{
    public ReferenceType ReferenceType { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Referent { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas on how to sort this?

Comment: So `ReferenceType` is an enum which can either  be `References` or `Quotes`?

Comment: why is this so hard? just iterate through items; start from 0, get the next entity from quotes if `index + 1 % 5 = 0`, else get the next one from references.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Here's a link to a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzvx24wiq7umzfr/testimonials.png?dl=0

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. Just a good way to know how to iterate through this.

Comment: Posting a screenshot on an external site is a really bad idea.  Many people (including me) can't see it because firewall rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) for both reference-types which is similar to a dictionary so rather efficient. Then use a `for`-loop and `Enumerable.Skip`/`Take` to create packages from each sequence and `Enumerable.Concat` to  put them together. Finally add them to a new `List<ReferenceItem>`:

```
var lookup = items.ToLookup(i => i.ReferenceType);
var sortedItems = new List<ReferenceItem>(items.Count);
for (int refIX = 0, quoteIX = 0; refIX < items.Count; refIX += 4, quoteIX++)
{
   var refPackage = lookup[ReferenceType.References].Skip(refIX).Take(4);
   var quotePackage = lookup[ReferenceType.Quotes].Skip(quoteIX).Take(1);
   sortedItems.AddRange(refPackage.Concat(quotePackage));
}
```

Here is the sample that i've used for testing:

```
var items = new List<ReferenceItem>() { 
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.Quotes, Counter = 1 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 2 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.Quotes, Counter = 3 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 4 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 5 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 6 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 7 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 8 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 9 },
    new ReferenceItem{ ReferenceType = ReferenceType.References, Counter = 10 }
};
```

Comment: I tested both solutions, and have to come to the conclusion that yours is the better approach. Both simplicity and performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code of how I would do it.  While merging put them in the order you want.

```
List<ReferenceItem> result = new List<ReferenceItem>();

while (References.Count >= 4 && Quotes.Count >= 1)
{
   // note pseudo code, how you do the add might be different.
   reference = References.Dequeue();
   result.Add(reference);
   reference = References.Dequeue();
   result.Add(reference);
   reference = References.Dequeue();
   result.Add(reference);
   reference = References.Dequeue();
   result.Add(reference);

   quote = Quotes.Dequeue();
   result.Add(quote);           
}

// handle edge cases where there are less than 4 items in Ref and 1 in Quote
// (this was not specified in the question)
```

Note, there are tricks you can do using Linq and Zip() or Aggregate(), but I don't believe you gain much from using those in this case.  The code above is clear and will be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your list into a quotes and a reference list, using the `.Where()` method:

```
var quotes = records.Where(r => r.ReferenceType == ReferenceType.Quote);
var references = records.Where(r => r.ReferenceType == ReferenceType.Reference);
```

Then in a loop you iterate through the items and dependent on the index you pick either a reference or a quote and add it to your result list.
Your condition could look like this:

```
if (index % 5 == 0) {
    //pick one from quotes and put it into the result list
}
else {
    //pick one from references and put it into the result list
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell they are already split.  The problem is not the merge (which he has done) -- it is having them sorted as described after the merge.  (My answer suggests merging them as he wants the final output.)

Comment: I'm going with this solution. For me the most straight forward. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: This solution will be rather inefficient since both queries are executed completely in the loop for every iteration.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure why you have decided to put them all in one collection......but you can use a custom sorting of a list [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx)  I have used this before and its very powerful.

Comment: This is not close to an answer -- it suggests a technique (and a poor one at that).

Comment: @BenTheSAintheUK Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for advice on how to answer a question.

Comment: Because I want to make it easy for myself in my template (MVC)